# Issue with OnCLick in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Here is the simple redirect function in my cod behind my .aspx file

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void GoToClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("LoginPage.aspx");
}
}
```

Pretty basic.

Here is the asp:LinkButton that calls it

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LoginLink" runat="server" Text="Login" Font-Bold="true" OnClick="GoToClicked" ></asp:LinkButton>
```

Whenever I attempt to build I get the following error:

```
 Error  1   'GoToClicked' is not a member of 'ASP.default_aspx'.       C:\Users\urMom\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\WebSites\HW_2\Default.aspx   65
```

What am I doing wrong? I have tried to following:

Using Server.Transfer instead

Changing the function from protected to public

Trying with and without an id tag (both caps and lowercase)

Comment: Is there any reason you didn't doubleclick the link button and write the code in the IDE generated method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="LoginLink" runat="server" Text="Login" Font-Bold="true" OnClick="GoToClicked"></asp:LinkButton>
```

Capitalization is important. `GoToCLicked` should be `GoToClicked`.

Additionally, the class name in your error message does not line up with the class name shown in your code behind class. You need to make sure these are in sync, double check the `@Page` directive at the top of your ASPX page.

Comment: @MadisonC.Brewer The class name in your error message appears out of sync with the actual class name shown in the code behind (.aspx.cs). What does the `@Page` directive look like at the top of your ASPX page?

Comment: Figured it out. I was missing a line from the top of my .aspx file

Comment: That's exactly what I was missing.

Answer (score 4):

Spelling mistake at

```
Text="Login" Font-Bold="true" OnClick="GoToCLicked" ></asp:LinkButton>
                                    -----^
```

This should be `GoToClicked`